# Extract key and params from shopify translation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text pattern ([Shopify Doc](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/internationalizing/translation-filter)):

```
{{- 'blog.comment.email' | t -}}
{{ 'layout.header.hello_user' | t: name: customer.first_name }}
{{ 'layout.comment.metadata' | t: author: comment.author, email: comment.email  }} 
{{'layout.comment.metadata'|t:author:comment.author,email:comment.email}}
```

And I need to get the 'name' and the 'keys' of the params.

```
{{- 'blog.comment.email' | t -}} 
#expected_result = [blog.comment.email]

{{ 'layout.header.hello_user' | t: name: customer.first_name }}
#expected_result = [layout.header.hello_user, name]

{{ 'layout.comment.metadata' | t: author: comment.author, email: comment.email  }}
#expected_result = [layout.comment.metadata, author, email]

//without spaces    
{{'layout.comment.metadata'|t:author:comment.author,email:comment.email}}
#expected_result = [layout.comment.metadata, author, email]
```

Regexps

```
{{- 'blog.comment.email' | t -}}
{{-? *'(.*)' *\| *t *-?}} works for the first case.
result = [blog.comment.email]

{{ 'layout.header.hello_user' | t: name: customer.first_name }}
{{-? *'(.*?)' *\| *t:? *((.+): *.*?)* *-?}} "works" for the second case,
result = [layout.header.hello_user, name: customer.first_name, name] 
#expected_result = [layout.header.hello_user, name]
```

But it extracts 'name: customer.first_name' too, and i only need 'layout.header.hello_user' and 'name'

I can't get the third option to work, I have tried this:

```
{{ 'layout.comment.metadata' | t: author: comment.author, email: comment.email  }}
{{-? *'(.*?)' *\| *t:? *(([A-Za-z0-9]+): *.*?)* *-?}}
result = [layout.header.hello_user, name: email: comment.email, email]
#expected_result = [layout.header.hello_user, author, email]
```

but it only extracts the last param.

There is no limit in quantity of params

It is required that the "|t" or "| t" or "|   t" is present

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next regex `(?<={{-?\s*'(?<key>[^']+)'\s*\|\s*t\s*(?::(?:\s*\w+\s*:\s*[.\w]+\s*,)*)?)(?:\s*(?<param>\w+)\s*:\s*[.\w]+\s*)?(?=(?:,\s*\w+\s*:\s*[.\w]+\s*)*-?}})`.

To try the regex online and get an explanation, please click [here](https://regex101.com/r/ASPNel/2).

But the proposed solution assumes further processing, since each separate match is a key-param pair, and not a key-params.

**Caution:** the regex101.com cannot process this regex in Safari running on my iPad with iOS 11.4.

Comment: This doesn't work without spaces {{'layout.comment.metadata'|t:author:comment.author,email:comment.email}}